# Can I write text stored as objects into the "alt" attribute for an image tag with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was given a task at MDN to create an image gallery. These were the requirements:

1. Declare a const array listing the filenames of each image, such as
   *'pic1.jpg'*
2. Declare a const object listing the alternative text for each image.
3. Loop through the array of filenames, and for each one, insert an img-tag inside the *".thumb-bar"* div-element that embeds that image in the page **along with its alternative text.**
4. Add a click event listener to each img-tag inside the *"thumb-bar"* div-element so that, when they are clicked, the corresponding image and alternative text are shown in the displayed img-tag.
5. Add a click event listener to the button-element so that when it is clicked, a darkened effect is applied to the full-size image. When it is clicked again, the darkened effect is removed again.

I would be so grateful if you can help me with this complete task. Although, where I actually need aid is in the **3rd** part where I am to include each image **along with its alternative text.** This part was pretty easy (possibly because the images are stored in arrays - which can easily be looped - unlike objects). But I got stuck at the alt text for each image source.

You will notice that the alt texts for each image, unlike the image sources, are stored as *Objects*.

In dev tools, I saw that I was able to include the alt-text, but the problem is that just one text is injected into all img-tags. Just when I thought I was close to finishing up the **3rd** part did I encounter this problem.

You will also notice that I attempted converting the **Object** for the alt texts into an **Array** of alt text.

```js
const displayedImage = document.querySelector('.displayed-img');
const thumbBar = document.querySelector('.thumb-bar');

const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');

/* Declaring the array of image filenames */
const imagesArrayOfFileNames = ['https://images.pexels.com/photos/935944/pexels-photo-935944.jpeg', 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/3769151/pexels-photo-3769151.jpeg', 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/2724748/pexels-photo-2724748.jpeg', 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/1462630/pexels-photo-1462630.jpeg', 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/1216589/pexels-photo-1216589.jpeg']

const imageAltText = new Object()
imageAltText.name1 = 'Child reading a bible'
imageAltText.name2 = 'Woman in hospital bed'
imageAltText.name3 = 'Kitchen view of a house'
imageAltText.name4 = 'A girl\'s photo at school'
imageAltText.name5 = 'Two workers at an industry'

/* Looping through images */
for (let imgFileName of imagesArrayOfFileNames) {
  const newImage = document.createElement('img');
  newImage.setAttribute('src', imgFileName);

  // convert object to array
  Object.keys(imageAltText).forEach(function(altKey, altVal) {
    newImage.setAttribute('alt', imageAltText[altKey]);
  })
  thumbBar.appendChild(newImage);
}


/* Wiring up the Darken/Lighten button */
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  width: 640px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.full-img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  /*min-width: 640px;*/
  width: 640px;
  height: 480px;
}

.full-img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 640px;
  height: 480px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

button {
  border: 0;
  background: rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.6);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px white;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
}

.thumb-bar img {
  display: block;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <title>Image gallery</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Image gallery example</h1>

  <div class="full-img">
    <img class="displayed-img" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/935944/pexels-photo-935944.jpeg" alt="Closeup of a human eye" />
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <button class="dark">Darken</button>
  </div>

  <div class="thumb-bar"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either convert object to array, but you can quite easily calculate the key to use fetching value from the object.

```js
/* Declaring the array of image filenames */
const imagesArrayOfFileNames = ['https://images.pexels.com/photos/935944/pexels-photo-935944.jpeg', 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/3769151/pexels-photo-3769151.jpeg', 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/2724748/pexels-photo-2724748.jpeg', 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/1462630/pexels-photo-1462630.jpeg', 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/1216589/pexels-photo-1216589.jpeg']

const imageAltText = new Object()
imageAltText.name1 = 'Child reading a bible'
imageAltText.name2 = 'Woman in hospital bed'
imageAltText.name3 = 'Kitchen view of a house'
imageAltText.name4 = 'A girl\'s photo at school'
imageAltText.name5 = 'Two workers at an industry'

/* Looping through images */

imagesArrayOfFileNames.forEach(function (imgFileName, index) {
  const newImage = document.createElement('img');
  newImage.setAttribute('src', imgFileName);
  newImage.setAttribute('alt', imageAltText['name' + (index+1)]);
  console.log(newImage)
  // thumbBar.appendChild(newImage);
});

// Alternatively, convert to array:
console.log(Object.values(imageAltText))
```

Comment: BOOM! In other words, you just made my day. Thank you.

Comment: Could you try to explain further how you got it right?

Comment: to access a property of an object you have direct access using key inside brackets. so if you have `object = {something:12}` then you can `value = object["some" + "thing"]` and it'll be 12. So I used `"name" + index` in the loop to get "name1", "name2" keys etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the short and simple solution.

Instead of using for loop just use foreach loop.

```
$.each(imagesArrayOfFileNames, function (altKey, imgFileName) {
  const newImage = document.createElement('img');
  newImage.setAttribute('src', imgFileName);
  newImage.setAttribute('alt', Object.values(imageAltText)[altKey]);
  // console.log('img', newImage);
  thumbBar.appendChild(newImage);
});
```

Comment: Is this a forEach() loop? I tried including it in the code, but it did not work.

Comment: Did you try this answer in the code? Maybe I missed something.